# Struggling to resolve resource for route in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I'm currently working on a web app that uses Django REST Framework for the back end and AngularJS for the front end. I'm still fairly new to Angular and I'm struggling to get the list of projects to resolve before the page finishes rendering. Whenever the page loads, the Chromeconsole reports the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: projectsProvider <- projects <- HomeCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$injector/unpr?p0=projectsProvider%20%3C-%20projects%20%3C-%20HomeCtrl
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4264:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4411:39)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4269:45
    at getService (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4411:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4443:13)
    at ident.$get.extend.instance (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9001:34)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8111:36)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7543:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7418:30) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Here's the routes:

```
var app = angular.module('projectile', [
    'ngRoute',
    'btford.markdown',
    'projectile.controllers',
    'projectile.services'
])

.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
  $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}])

.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/static/templates/home.html',
      resolve: {
        projects: function (MultiProjectLoader) {
          return MultiProjectLoader();
        }
      },
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

Here's the controllers:

```
angular.module('projectile.controllers', [
        'projectile.directives',
        'projectile.services',
        'ngRoute',
        'btford.markdown'
])

.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, projects, Issue) {
  // Get open issues
  $scope.issues = Issue.query({ open: true });

  // Get projects
  $scope.projects = projects;
});
```

Here's the services:

```
angular.module('projectile.services', ['ngResource'])

.factory('Project', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/projects/:projectId');
})

.factory('MultiProjectLoader', function (Project, $q) {
  return function() {
    var delay = $q.defer();
    Project.query(function(projects) {
      delay.resolve(projects);
    }, function() {
      delay.reject('Unable to fetch projects');
    });
    return delay.promise;
  };
});
```

What's gone wrong? And how do I resolve it? If I use `debugger` inside the controller, `projects` is defined and contains the correct data, so I'm rather stumped.

I can just pass through `Project` and run `Project.query()` to get the result, but that means the page gets updated after it's rendered. I have a spinner directive in place and I want to wait for the request to finish before rendering the page, which I understand `resolve` is for.

Comment: @Claies No, it's not a typo. I'm trying to duplicate the functionality of [the GutHub app from the O'Reilly AngularJS book](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shyamseshadri/angularjs-book/master/chapter4/guthub/app/scripts/controllers/controllers.js).

Comment: I'm trying to browse the entire project repository now to see what might be different between your code and the sample.

Comment: @Claies - projects is not a service, it's a param provided by a route resolve

Comment: it seems that the `resolve` parameter isn't being handled correctly.  Which version of angular.js and angular-route.js are you using? And based on your code, it looks like you aren't doing any minification?

Comment: @Claies Angular and angular-route are both 1.4.2, installed via Bower. I'm not doing any minification at present - I'll probably switch it to using Browserify later on and use Gulp to minify the code then. Updating to 1.4.6 doesn't change the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your factory directly returning a promise, you should not call the function `MultiProjectLoader` factory. Instead you should only return promise from the resolve function.

```
projects: function (MultiProjectLoader) {
    //removed function bracket
    return MultiProjectLoader; //returned the promise directive from resolve.
}
```

But as singleton is considered you shouldn't define factory this way. You should return object from factory and that will have various method which will used for different purpose.

**Factory**

```
.factory('MultiProjectLoader', function(Project, $q) {
    return {
        projectQuery: function() {
            return roject.query().$promise.then(function(projects) {
                return projects;
            }, function(error) {
                return error;
            });
        };
    }
});
```

**Resolve**

```
projects: function (MultiProjectLoader) {
    return MultiProjectLoader.projectQuery(); //returned the promise
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't fix it. Still getting the same error.